# append existing values in table as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On submit action (from my standard RoR edit view), I want to store existing data fields as an ongoing textdump in the same row.

The controller should "push" the value of a data field (e.g. `current_location`) to a `text` in the tablefield `logdump` with `\n` as a separator.

After some travelling and changes of "current_location" there will be e.g. the following text stored in the tablefield `logdump`:

`London
Rio
Athen
Berlin
New York`

I thought about storing this log in a extra log table, but this string dump solution into my existing table, is enough for my needs.

Comment: Your question is not clear. _I thought about storing this log in a table,_ - ok so where are you now storing then?

Comment: Yes you are right, this was unclear. I want to store this data in the same row, in one big text field. (I used the word string not in RoR meaning, I mean textdump)

Comment: What is your Database?

Comment: @MrH I am using standard RoR sqlite for development and plan to use mysql on production

Answer (score 0):

you probably you need serialize it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :current_location, Array
end

u = User.new
#=> #<User id: nil, current_location: [], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
u.current_location = %w(London Rio Athen Berlin New\ York)
u.save
```

Comment: thx for your answer. For a serialized solution this a good match, but currently I am actually searching fo a deserialization solution.

Comment: understand but this also serve to deserialize. Because you need to inform rails how it serialize to deserialize